# Hortonworks 2.4 Sandbox fails on Ambari NiFi install

Tags: hadoop, apache-nifi, ambari

The Ambari/NiFi install fails from the http/Gui with this message:

*resource_management.core.exceptions.Fail: Execution of 'unzip /tmp/nifi-0.5.1.1.1.2.0-32.zip -d /opt >> /var/log/nifi/nifi-setup.log' returned 9.   End-of-central-directory signature not found.  Either this file is not
  a zipfile, or it constitutes one disk of a multi-part archive.  In the
  latter case the central directory and zipfile comment will be found on
  the last disk(s) of this archive.
unzip:  cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/nifi-0.5.1.1.1.2.0-32.zip or
        /tmp/nifi-0.5.1.1.1.2.0-32.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/nifi-0.5.1.1.1.2.0-32.zip.ZIP, period.*

The bottom line is that wget never finds the tarball from the sandbox's configured location to bring it over. I realize this version of NiFi is an ancient one--which may be why its missing in action, but this HDF/HDP 2.4 sandbox is the only one I can get to run on my thin resources at the moment. 2.6 takes my host's resources over the tipping point.

I was able to manually install the 0.5.1x version by executing these steps after downloading an archive copy from Apache NiFi into the VMWare fileshare drive:

```
cd /opt
tar -xzvf /mnt/hgfs/myfileshare/nifi-0.5.1.tar.gz
nifi-0.5.1/bin/nifi.sh install
service nifi start
```

I can see the canvas from sandbox.hortonworks.com:9090/nifi, so I know the install on the sandbox was successful.

Now I am stuck in an endless Ambari loop where the ambari agent thinks the product isn't installed, so I won't be able to stop/start NiFi from Ambari. This would mean a manual start on each VM power cycle. Other than freezing the VM, is there a work around for the constant attempt at an unnecessary install and the inability to invoke the service from Ambari?

Answer (score 2):

Although this question is old and may not be relevant anymore,but It came up a few times during searching for a solution for my own problem. So here is the solution I tried and it worked.

So, from the error it's clear that `.zip` file is corrupted and/or was not the required format.

> unzip: cannot find zipfile directory in one of /tmp/nifi-0.5.1.1.1.2.0-32.zip or /tmp/nifi-0.5.1.1.1.2.0-32.zip.zip, and cannot find /tmp/nifi-0.5.1.1.1.2.0-32.zip.ZIP, period.

you can check this file in the directory `/tmp` from the unix shell. So, to solve this issue, remove that file from the `tmp` directory and reinstall/add service using `Ambari` and it will be able to restart the process from start. This remove step was required b/c `Amabri` checks for the file in `tmp` and every time it was trying to use this corrupted file.